# setters and getters simple use?

Tags: class, setter, getter

**Question the SECOND PART**

Thanks for the great help so far..
OK I've made progress but something still isn't right.
My SpaceWarz class is as follows:

```
public class SpaceWarz {
    private boolean deePad; //access to this is restricted
    public boolean getDeePad()
    {       return this.deePad;     }

    public void setDeePad(boolean value)
    {      this.deePad = value;     }
    }
```

and it is happily sharing values with my Render class where the bulk of my code resides:

```
SpaceWarz sw = new SpaceWarz();
public void LoadGameSettings(){
    sw.setDeePad(_dPad);    // send value to SpaceWarz class
    _dPad = sw.getDeePad(); // get value from SpaceWarz class
}
```

BUT values are NOT getting through from my onCreate method in the other class. The game data is loaded in the onCreate method and saved onDestroy so it's a problem if I can't then send that data on:

```
    SpaceWarz sw = new SpaceWarz(); 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// SET SHARED DATA 
            _dPad = true; // debug value to be removed.
            sw.setDeePad(_dPad);
// SET SHARED DATA          
                    }
```

Any ideas how to put this right?

<--snip-->

**Question the FIRST PART**

Need some very basic help with setters and getters. I'm trying to move data between a class containing my onCreate method and one containing my main code to load and save game settings when my app starts and stops. I was trying to use Bundles but It was suggested using setters and getters would be simpler.

I've created a 3rd class called SpaceWarz:

```
package com.clockworkrobot.spacewarz;

public class SpaceWarz {

    private boolean deePad; //access to this is restricted

    public boolean getDeePad()
    {       return this.deePad;     }

    public void setDeePad(boolean value)
    {      this.deePad = value;     }

   }
```

Am I setting that right and can anyone outline exactly how I set and get the value from my other classes as I'm not getting the syntax right causing a crash :(

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The syntax has no errors really... When you instantiate your SpaceWarz class, your get and set will work. What type of errors are you experiencing?

Comment: I've added some more information. Im not getting the crash now but values are not being adopted from my onCreate method :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question but to use those setters and getters that you wrote, you will have to have a SpaceWarz object created somewhere in your code.

```
SpaceWarz sw = new SpaceWarz();
```

Then you can call its setter or getter method.

```
if (sw.getDeePad())
{
   //do something
}

sw.setDeePad(false);
```

Comment: thanks. I'm simply trying to pass some values between classes so the game I'm writing will retain its setup settings.. I've very little experience programming but have managed to cludge together quite a complex little app. This little detail is just giving me a lot of trouble. Lack of fundamentals I think. ANYWAY. I se how the set but works but i don't get why there's an if there in the get. How do i recover my boolean value from that?

Comment: OH it's ok I get it.. I was looking for this:  _dPad = sw.getDeePad(); and it works beautifully. THANKS Timulus and dispake. you just broke the back of a prob that's been bugging me for WEEKS!

Comment: GAH! had to be too good to be true. OK it HALF works.. any ideas why it's failing to get values from my onCreate method?

Answer (score 1):

Having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do.  But getters/setters are as simple as they sound. Here's a small example of how it would work.

```
public class MainClass() {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

         SpaceWarz game = new SpaceWarz();
         game.setDeePee(true);

         if (game.getDeePee()) // if true
             game.setDeePee(false); // turn off
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got the other code snippit half working (it's doing more or less the exact same thing I think? ) but I've re-edited my post to explain the further hitch :)

Comment: Hard to follow the scope of your code.  Can't tell whether loadGameSettings() and onCreate() are in the same class?  If so, they should both have access to that instance of SpaceWarz sw.  If not, then you need to address each method's reference to the SpaceWarz object or make implement SpaceWarz as a singleton.